# How does spark driver handle data bigger than its memory? Think of TBs of data on a cluster and we do a reduce by key or a collect

Tags: apache-spark

How does spark driver handle data bigger than its memory? Think of TBs of data on a cluster and we do a reduce by key or a collect. Does it spill data to disk? Even if it does, what happens when we have a GB of Disk space on the driver and We are handling TBs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark won't "handle" too much data coming back to the driver. The driver will run into an out-of-memory error.

Collecting or running actions that require data to go to a single node (driver or not) should always be done with caution.

As warned by the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#printing-elements-of-an-rdd):

> This can cause the driver to run out of memory, though, because collect() fetches the entire RDD to a single machine; if you only need to print a few elements of the RDD, a safer approach is to use the take(): rdd.take(100).foreach(println).

Comment: Could you please explain how a shuffle works? Since it is a common to do a shuffle on a large dataset.

Comment: @HemanthGowda Shuffles are just about moving data around to locate it where it is to be used in computation. Unless the application explicitly manipulates partitions, Spark takes care of it. Partitions, however, determine data that must fit on a single node, and this is where problems can be encountered (spark can use the disk to store some data when it doesn't fit in memory - subject to storage levels). Again, actions pulling data onto a single node (collect(), take(), etc.) are dangerous as Spark will give the requested data to the node (in memory), if the node can't handle it, an OOM occurs